# Como instanciar una clase de tipo SQLiteOpenHelper en otro clase simple

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqlite3

tengo dos clases una de tipo SQLiteOpenHelper y otra normal

```
public class dbdata extends SQLiteOpenHelper{}
```

y otra

```
public class parsers {}
```

La clase Parsers, lee un json, y quiero que al momento de leer envie a guardar en la base sqlite, pero no puedo instanciar la clase de la base.

```
 mDbCliente=new dbdata();
 mDbCliente.nuevoCliente(cliente);
```

Se que debo pasarle un parametro al constructor, pero no se como haria en este caso, la idea es hacer fuera de un activity.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sus comenatarios

Answer (score 2):

En el caso que la clase no sea `Activity` o `Fragment`, lo que tienes que realizar es recibir en el constructor de la clase el contexto, ya sea de la aplicación o de la `Activity`, esto para poder instanciar tu database manager :

```
mDbCliente = new dbdata(mContext);
```

por ejemplo:

```
public class MyClass {

private Context mContext;

   //Recibe el contexto.
   public MyClass (Context context) {
       mContext = context
   }

  private void miMethod(){
   ...
   ...
   mDbCliente = new dbdata(mContext);
   ...
   ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> la idea es hacer fuera de un activity.

Sin embargo, a la larga hay una llamada que viene de un Activity, por lo que tu clase Parser debería recibir, ya sea en su constructor o en la llamada al método específico que se está ejecutando el Context de tu Activity.

Comment: Entonces deberia pasar un context al construct de la clase parsers.?

Comment: Claro, o al método en el que quieras usarlo:

Parser p = new Parser(getApplicationContext());

o

Parser p = new Parser();
p.metodo(getApplicationContext());